# php intl extension missing

Tags: php, macos, cakephp, frameworks

I'm using a Mac Mojave. Installed `MAMP`. Composer Version `1.8.4` . When trying to create cakePHP project inside the htdocs by using

`composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app test`

The terminal is giving error

```
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/intl.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/intl.so, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/intl.so in Unknown on line 0
Installing cakephp/app (3.7.1)
  - Installing cakephp/app (3.7.1): Loading from cache
Created project in patientcare
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.7.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.7.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.7.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.7.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.7.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.7.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.7.* -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.7.0, 3.7.1, 3.7.2, 3.7.3, 3.7.4, 3.7.5].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Doing some research on the internet, I tried to enable the `intl extension` in the php files in `etc/php.ini` and also the `php.ini` file inside the MAMP folder.

I am stuck on this for a whole day and had not been able to make any progress.

Please help me.

Comment: What means you have tried - is it now installed or not? If not, then you have edited the wrong php.ini.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz edited `/etc/php.ini` and added `extension=intl.so` and then edited `/Applications/MAMP/conf/php7.2.10/php.ini` and added `extension=intl.so`. Still i'm getting the same error.

Comment: Use phpinfo to find out, where the LOADED ini file is. Eg. write a php script with only "phpinfo()" in it, then call it through a browser

Comment: @LarsStegelitz did as mentioned  - -`Loaded Configuration File  /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/conf/php.ini`.  In that config file also `extension=intl.so` is enabled.

Comment: `intl
Internationalization support enabled
version  1.1.0
ICU version  56.1
ICU Data version  56.1
ICU TZData version  2015f
ICU Unicode version  8.0 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is NOT that the extension is not enabled (it IS).

Your problem is this:

> dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/intl.so

This path and/or file just does not exist. Check the ini for the "extension_dir" folder setting. Locate the proper folder and adjust the "extension_dir" folder setting accordingly.

Comment: how can i find the missing file?, in extension directory, i do not see 'intl.so' file. please advise, how did you fix it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that generally xammp / mamp / etc tend to have different php.ini files for command line and web, so the best idea is to find figure out which one is being used by command line, running `php -i` in your command line.

Once you figured out the right file, enable it there. You can check if the extension is loaded with `php -m`.

Comment: `php -i` -> `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc` . `extension=intl.so` enabled.        `php -m ` -> `intl` not listed in the PHP module list.